# Irritating magnify effect on mouse hover

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, magnify

Here is my [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m9tHb/12/)

I have three link enclosed with `ul`  `li` tag.I want my each link to magnify when someone mouse hover it. I know it can be done using `absolute` positioning and `z-index`. I tried something but I am not getting it right.T he problem with my jsFiddle is the 2nd `li` element after magnifying takes two line.

Can someone help me with it.

Here is my HTML

```
<ul>
<li> <a href="#">Home</a> </li>
<li> <a href="#">About us</a> </li>
<li> <a href="#">Contact us</a> </li>
</ul>
```

Here is my Jquery

```
$(function(){
var t = 10;
$('li').each(function(e,i){
    $(this).offset({top:50,left:t});
    t+=100;
});

$('a').hover(function(){
    $(this).animate({'z-index':'1','font-size':'30px'},50);
      },
      function(){
          $(this).animate({'z-index':'0','font-size':'15px'},50);
    });
});
```

Here is CSS :

```
a {
text-decoration:none;
font-size: 15px;
}
ul {
list-style-type:none;
}
li {
padding-left: 50px;
width:100px;
text-align:center;
position:absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your white space

you have to modify your css to adjust the whitespace

```
li {
    padding-left: 50px;
    width:100px;
    text-align:center;
    position:absolute;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

I have updated your fiddle have a look here http://jsfiddle.net/m9tHb/13/

hope that helps